# Is there any proof that there are only 3 so-called "neon numbers"?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, decimal-expansion

The phrase "neon number" is sometimes used for a number where: square the number, add the digits of that in base 10, and you get the original number.

So, 9 is a neon number (-> 81, 8+1, 9)

Indeed it is usually said there are only three neon numbers (0, 1, and 9).

Surprisingly I couldn't google any proof of this. (All the numbers up to a few billion have been trivially tested.)

Is there a proof?

And angularly, are "neon numbers" of any value or interest at all, or is it just a quirky thing?

Comment: Pretty sure that for any base $n$, the sum of the digits of $(n-1)^2$ in that base equals $n-1$. For example, in base $8$, $7\times 7=61$, and in hexadecimal, F$\times$F$=$E$1$

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Suppose a number $m$ has $n$ digits. Then $m^2$ has atmost $2n$ digits.
The sum of digits of $m^2$ is at most $9\times 2n=18n$.
If the sum of digits of $m^2$ is equal to $m$ then $10^{n-1}\le m\le18n$.
This only true if $n<3$, so only single digit and double digit numbers can possibly be neon numbers.

---

You can prove using modular arithmetic that only numbers of the form $9k$ and $9k+1$ can be neon numbers. This reduces the number of positive integers that we have to check.

---

**EDIT**
Like [@JBentley](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/68497/jbentley) pointed out in the comments $0$ has to be considered separately because the inequality $10^{n-1}\le m$ does not hold.

Comment: so sober !!!  thx!

Comment: +1 although your inequality doesn't cover the case where m=0

Comment: @JBentley Unless you regard zero as having zero digits. Informally, we ignore leading zeroes (`1` could be written as `0001` but still only has one digit; so `0` _should be_ an empty string, but then we wouldn't see it!) More formally, if we use "successor of" notation, zero is `0`, one is `S0` etc. and so "number of digits" becomes "number of `S`s".

Comment: @TripeHound even if we accept that reasoning the inequality still doesn't work for the case where m=0 and n=0. The correct approach is simply to state the case for 0 as an exception.

Comment: @JBentley Yes, you're right. I think I was incorrectly "seeing" the inequality as 0 <= 0 <= 18.0 for n=m=0.

Comment: Hmm.  As a curiosity, is it a bit odd to say "Here's an equation that proves something. Oh, we know of one exception." - ?

Comment: @fattie Exception was a poor choice of word from me. Rather, it is a corner case which is part of the proof. It could have alternatively been stated as "If the sum of digits of m^2 is equal to m then either m=0 or 10^n−1 ≤ m ≤18n."

Comment: JBentley - gotchya, it makes sense!